# Keyboard and Mouse Lagging Unexpectedly while using any internet browser

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I'm using a Macbook Pro 5,5 and somewhat recently a bug has cropped up. At some point while using any browser (I prefer Chrome, but this has occurred while using Firefox as well) the keyboard and mouse will begin to lag pretty badly. There is a noticeable lag in typing, and the mouse pointer will dance around the screen. A system reboot fixes the issue, and the frequency at which the problem occurs is very random (I've gone as long as a week without the issue happening, and as short a time as simply relaunching the browser after a reboot).

If anyone has any suggestions, I would gladly appreciate the help.

Comment: What version browsers/Ubuntu? Are there any plugins that you can disable?

Comment: I'm using 12.04 and the Chrome browser version is 33.0.1750.117. To be honest, I wouldn't know which scripts are running, or which ones are causing the issue otherwise.

Comment: Under -> Tools -> Add-ons -> Extensions or Plug-ins - Check those, your can temporarily disable the extensions.

Comment: Thanks. Basically, try disabling them to figure out which one is causing the problem, and go from there.

Comment: Yep, it will at least rule out things like flash.

Comment: I disabled all of the extensions, unfortunately the problem still occurred. I do notice it happens more often when I go to sites that might be heavier on scripts, like YouTube for example.

Comment: Another development: I woke up this morning to find the keyboard and trackpad were lagging. However, Chrome wasn't running. The only thing that was running was a music player and Thunderbird.